# Pass in a list/array/collection into a WCF Data Services (OData) Service Operation

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, odata

I would have created a service operation that takes an IEnumerable param.

How can I call this from the Client side?

I read this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/05/26/service-operations-and-the-wcf-data-services-client.aspx) and it showed me how to set it up.  But I don't see how to pass in an arry/collection/list.

I guess I could convert to a comma seperated string and then parse it out again, but that seems like a hack just to pass a list of longs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service operations only support primitive type arguments currently. So there's no simple way to pass in a list of values. Using the comma separated string if possible is usually a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user Get Method for this operation, the parameters cannot be like list or collections.
I suggest you use Post Method, and put all of your parameters in the request body.
Hope this can help you !